# making compound xpath statement for xslt: match

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, docbook, docbook-5

Here's a generic XSLT 1.0 question which I need to know to write an XSLT statement for processing docbook xml files.    In my docbook XML, I'm trying to write a compound xpath statement in XSLT 1.0  that says, hardcode a new attribute "class = "play" for p tags in html output.

I want this action to be done for **every** `<para>` tag which does NOT have these attributes

1. role="normal-play-paragraph" AND
2. role ="no-indent" AND
3. "role="line-verse"

Here is my XML source:

```
<chapter xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        version="5.0" xml:id="play">
  <title> Hamlet </title>

    <para role="no-indent"> SPHINX. Do you think about it very much?</para>
    <para role="normal-play-para"> INTERVIEWER. I do so say. </para>
    <para>SPHINX. Hello </para>
    <para> INTERVIEWER. dddddWhy I do so say. </para>
    <para> SPHINX. Yes. </para>
    <para role="line-verse"> Cosmologists have theorized or guessed</para>
</chapter>
```

I want the HTML output to look like this after Docbook XSLT processes it:

```
<html>
<body>
<p class="no-indent">SPHINX. Do you think about it very much? much. </p>
 <p class="normal-play-para"> INTERVIEWER. I do so say. </p>
   <p class="play">SPHINX. Hello </p>
   <p class="play">INTERVIEWER. dddddWhy I do so say. </p>
   <p class="play">SPHINX. Yes.  </p>
 <p class="line-verse"> Cosmologists have theorized or guessed</p>
</body>
<html>
```

The docbook xslt has 2 mechanisms at work which you don't really need to know about.

First, in `<para role="">` elements, the value of role is changed into class of p. This is the default behavior. 
Second, I'm using a special mode to hardcode a `"class='play'"` into p tags.

```
<xsl:template match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para" mode="class.attribute" >
  <xsl:param name="class" select="local-name(.)"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="class">play</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I want class="play" to be hardcoded only when there are other attributes & values NOT present.  I can modify the above statement to exclude all para tags with  the attribute role="line-verse" :

```
  <xsl:template match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para[@role != 'line-verse']" mode="class.attribute" >
    <xsl:param name="class" select="local-name(.)"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">play</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

But I need more than that. I want to exclude not only role= "line-verse," but also role="no-indent" and role="normal-play-para".

So I have to change the value of the xpath statement in the match attribute so that it excludes three attribute values. I haven't the foggiest idea how to do that. Does anybody know? Thanks.

**Update about Answer:**

First, I want to thank all of you for taking the time to understand my question and formulate an answer. I should mention that I am still a novice on this stuff, and also, my question was a little unfair because I am using some sophisticated/complicated Docbook XSL. Therefore I need an answer that doesn't cause collisions with the Docbook XSL stylesheets. Also, I realize that you wrote transformations that may be perfectly valid answers in generating html output if I were not also importing the docbook xsl.

The answer which I chose as "best" here may not be the most elegant, but simply the one that worked for me in the case when I am importing the epub3 docbook-ns stylesheets.  So Mr. Rishe's one line answer actually does exactly I need it to do even if it isn't as elegant.

I really don't know what's going on in this customization which I started out with:

```
<xsl:template match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para" mode="class.attribute" >
  <xsl:param name="class" select="local-name(.)"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="class">play</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

What I do know is that it's invoking a `<xsl:template name="generate.class.attribute">` which is found here. `http://50.56.245.89/xsl-ns/xhtml-1_1/html.xsl`

Another thing. Dimitre Novatchev's 2 answers looks as though they would work. By the way,  you forgot to include the  `<xsl:param name="class" select="local-name(.)"/>` statement -- which is easily fixed -- and that solution works.

However, Dimitre, I have another question. The second answer you gave used variables, which looks simple and functional.  If I try it, my Saxon 6.5 parser gives a validation error. *(E [Saxon6.5.5] The match pattern in xsl:template may not contain references to variables).* Maybe it's something simple like a typo. But is it possible that variables are not allowed in XSLT 1.0 template matches?

Comment: I tried writing three separate statements, each of which excluded a certain attribute value. Dumb, I know, but maybe it would work. Saxon complains of an "ambiguous match" and doesn't leave those good roles intact and instead hardcodes "class="play" for every p tag universally. That is bad.

Comment: Could you show us the part of the XSLT that is invoking these "class.attribute" templates?

Comment: JLRishe, I didn't want you to wade into the Docbook XSLT stylesheets too much because all I really needed was an xpath statement. If you are interested, the URL to the relevant piece of Docbook XSLT for class.attribute is here: http://50.56.245.89/xsl-ns/xhtml-1_1/html.xsl

Comment: I see.  I had a look at that XSL and it's pretty meaty. And I agree, sometimes tacking on addendum to the XSLT is better than trying to modify stuff that's already there, especially when it's large and complex like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you give this a try:

```
<!-- Special handling for paras with one of the three roles -->
<xsl:template 
  match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para[@role = 'line-verse' or @role = 'normal-play-para' or @role - 'line-indent']" 
  mode="class.attribute" >
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="@role" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Other paras get the default class "play" -->
<xsl:template match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para" mode="class.attribute">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">play</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

One step further would be to have the `<xsl:attribute>` in the template that's calling these templates, and just have the needed value in the `class.attribute` templates themselves.  Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para">
    <p>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="class.attribute" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    ...
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Special handling for paras with one of the three roles -->
<xsl:template 
  match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para[@role = 'line-verse' or @role = 'normal-play-para' or @role - 'line-indent']" 
  mode="class.attribute" >
      <xsl:value-of select="@role" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- Other paras get the default class "play" -->
<xsl:template match="d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para" mode="class.attribute">
  <xsl:text>play</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

To specifically answer your original question, if you really needed a template that specifically matches `para`s that *don't* have one of those `@role` values, you could match on this XPath:

```
d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para[not(@role = 'line-verse' or @role = 'normal-play-para' or @role - 'line-indent')]
```

But I think the approach I've presented above (treat `para`s those roles as the special case, and treat everything else as the default) is the better way to go.

Comment: The one line suggestion which you suggested worked perfectly. I wrote some more comments at the end of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

**One possible solution is**:

```
  <xsl:template mode="class.attribute" match=
  "d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']
       /d:para[not(@role = 'line-verse' 
                  or @role = 'no-indent' 
                  or @role = 'normal-play-para'
                   )]"  >
    <xsl:attribute name="class">play</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

**However, I would use a more flexible and extensible solution,  that allows easy modification of the "non-play" values**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pNonPlayVals">
  <val>line-verse</val>
  <val>no-indent</val>
  <val>normal-play-para</val>
 </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template mode="class.attribute" match=
  "d:chapter[@xml:id = 'play']/d:para
         [not(@role = document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pNonPlayVals']/val)]"  >
    <xsl:attribute name="class">play</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, there, Dimitre, thanks for your answers -- see my comments at the end of my original question. I couldn't get Saxon 6.5 to validate the second answer you gave. Not sure why; it looks like it would work perfectly!

Comment: @idiotprogrammer, What do you mean by "I couldn't get Saxon 6.5 to validate the second answer you gave. " -- was there an error message, or if not, what was the problem?

Comment: When I added your second answer to my customization layer, Oxygen editor immediately highlighted the xsl:template mode="" line and gave this message. I wasn't able to run it. Your first answer worked though, and the second answer seems easier to maintain....

Comment: sorry, maybe you didn't see my edit on top. The message said, "(E [Saxon6.5.5] The match pattern in xsl:template may not contain references to variables). "

Comment: Yes, I'll correct this -- the condition involving the variable must be moved into the body of the template. Or, we should substitute the variable with its RHS.